# What's wrong with my code (missing letter - freecodecamp)?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code for the 'missing letter' challenge. The console log showed both 'undefined' and the missing letter which was d. I don't understand what happened. Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you!

```js
var str ="bce"; 
for (var i=0;i< str.length;i++){

    if(str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1) !==1){
      var  missing = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i-1)+1);
      console.log(missing);
     }
    else
     console.log(undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your loop at i=1; so that i-1 is atleast 0. When you start it at 0, i-1 becomes -1. Can the first letter in the sequence ever be missing letter? If you have to find only one missing number, you can log that and break the loop also.

```
var str ="bce"; 
for (var i=1;i< str.length;i++){

    if(str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1) !==1){
      var  missing = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i-1)+1);
      console.log(missing);
      break;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `i = 0`, you are probably getting an out of bounds error for your if statement

```
str.charCodeAt(i-1)
```

An index of `str.charCodeAt(-1)` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for index -1 on the first loop change it to this. start i at 1 instead of 0

```
for (var i=1;i< str.length;i++){

if(str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1) !==1){
  var  missing = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i-1)+1);
  console.log(missing);
 }
else
 console.log(undefined);
```

}